# USB devices disconnect when in use

Tags: usb, hardware-failure, connection, usb-storage

I am being zapped by electricity when i touch the PC case sharp corners where there is no paint for long time now however usb card reader used to work before it started to constantly getting disconnected, as well as phone, but only after i open file transfer, when its statically connected and not being used it don't get disconnected from PC.

Even reinstalled Windows 10 clean install and problem still there.

When i plug a USB to Micro-Usb cable and touch outside of micro-USB connector i am being zapped (shocked by electricity) slightly, also, not sure if its related

Motherboard is not installed on cooper legs its screwed directly into the case, mouse and keyboard work fine though.

Comment: Take it to a repair shop for correct diagnosis. We don't want to be responsible for an early death.

Comment: The motherboard must be installed on stand-offs otherwise there could be short-circuits where the soldered joints touch the case. Also, are you sure that the outlet which the power supply is plugged into is correctly earthed, and that the mains cable has an earth wire in it?

Comment: Why would an electrical fault be helped by reinstalling Windows?

Comment: Install the motherboard properly on standoffs, [edit] your question, to indicate if the ESD issue still exists

Comment: @Ramhound it may not be an ESD issue ... it may be a dangerous electrical issue with the house wiring

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is some kind of electrical short, probably from the motherboard that is touching the case somewhere, or a lack of ground wiring in the socket it is plugged into.

Despite that the voltage may be low, it is still not safe to run electrical equipment that is shorting out as there is a risk or personal injury or fire.

Reinstalling Windows does not solve this kind of problem, as it is a hardware problem, not a software problem.

I highly recommend that you take this computer to a repair shop to be inspected, because of the aforementioned risks. You should also ensure that your electrical outlets have ground wiring.